# How do I force a Time in utc when server is in another timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My server has system timezone "Europe/Paris"

I configured my Rails app  ( Rails 3.29)
    config.time_zone = 'Europe/London'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc

all event start/end dates are the stored in db  as :  "2013-01-02 10:00:00"

the issue is on scoping

```
scope :starting, lambda {|start_date_time|
  {:conditions => ["starts_at = ?", Event.db_datetime(start_date_time)] }
}
...
def self.db_datetime(date_time)
  Time.at(date_time.to_i).utc.to_s(:db)
end
```

when I create start_date_time filter ,
 I get a system local time-zoned datetime
    start_date_time = Time.new(2013, 1, 2, 10, 0, 0)
    2013-01-02 10:00:00 +0100

```
and Event.db_datetime(start_date_time) gives "2013-01-02 09:00:00" 
which cannot be found
```

Is there a way to force utc datetime so : 
    start_date_time = Time.new(2013, 1, 2, 10, 0, 0)  would give
    2013-01-02 10:00:00 UTC

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Time.at** - or **Time.new** - parses the time in the system local time zone, which here appears to be UTC+1.
That's why parsing 10:00 in UTC+1 becomes 09:00 in UTC.

I think the function you are looking for is

```
Time.zone.at                             #equivalent to Time.at
Time.zone.local(2013, 1, 2, 10, 0, 0)    #equivalent to Time.new
```

which will parse the given date and time in the time zone defined by

```
config.time_zone = 'Europe/London'
```

The result of this is a **TimeWithZone** object, which is a Rails extention to the ruby **Time**.

You can check this documentation page http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html for more informations about TimeWithZone.

You can use it this way; the db_datetime(date_time) method is not really necessary anymore :

```
# class Event
scope :starting, lambda {|start_date_time|
  {:conditions => ["starts_at = ?", start_date_time.to_s(:db)] }
}
# I think to_s(:db) already handle the .utc conversion part



## example
start_date_time = Time.zone.local(2013, 1, 2, 10, 0, 0) 
Event.starting(start_date_time)
```

Comment: Thanks you're right so once my dates are stored , I can search on date or on time (hour:mn) .. I force the filter (datetime) into a UTC
using :

  def self.db_datetime(date_time)
    Time.use_zone Rails.configuration.time_zone do
      Time.zone.local(date_time.year, date_time.month, date_time.day, date_time.hour, date_time.min, 0).to_s(:db)
    end
  end

Comment: Time.zone already uses the time_zone defined in your Rails configuration, so you don't need to redefine it. You can use Time.zone.local directly, or Time.zone.at(date_time.to_i).

Comment: I added an example in my anwser

Comment: Adrien , Happy New 2013 first ...  I would like to vote for your answer but I don't know how to do it ...  where should I click ?